# Проблема операторов сравнения JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

в общем есть код который сравнивает значения в двух инпутах, ищет в объектах цену, сортирует и выводит на экран. Мы имеем :

---

1. Кол-во контактов (назовем переменную К)
2. Кол во писем (назовем переменную П)
3. Цена (Ц)

---

У К и П общая цена, то есть допустим 1000 К и 10000 П стоят 7$,
а там 2000 К и 120000 П стоят уже 20$, как бы я не переставлял операторы сравнивания, всегда либо К либо П имеет приоритет и отслеживается значение только одного из двух параметров. Как правильно их расставить что бы если значения если в поле1 допустим было 1000 К, а в поле2 10000 П, или наоборот то выбиралось значение которое выше по стоимости? Так же с радостью приму любые советы по оптимизации и сокращению так как в js не слишком давно) (Это отрывок кода, всего таких айтемов 6, и по ним идет сортировка по цене)

полный код тут [https://codepen.io/johnneon/pen/JjdbKZY]

```js
   var sendgrid = {
        name: "sendgrid",
        2000: 0.00,
        7000: 15.00,
        8000: 25.00,
        20000: 50.00,
        45000: 120.00,
        80000: 200.00,
        100000: 450.00,
        190000: 900.00 
    };
     var sendgridContacts = {
          2000: 2000,
          7000: 7000,
          8000: 8000,
          20000: 20000,
          45000: 45000,
          80000: 80000,
          100000: 100000,
          190000: 190000  
      };
      var subscribe = {
        sale: "\"Бесплатно\"",
        sub: "Подписка",
        optimal: "\"Оптимальный\"",
        ess: "\"Essentials\"",
        standart: "\"Standard\"",
        prerium: "\"Premium\"",
        basic: "\"Basic\"",
        advanced: "\"Advanced\"",
        enterprise: "\"Enterprise\"",
        ind:  "Индивидуальный"
    };
    
    var ratesSendgrid = [];
    
    $('.calcContact, .calcEmail').on('change paste keyup focus', function() {
    if($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000 ||
         $('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[2000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.sale);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[2000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 6001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 15000 || 
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 2001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 7000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[7000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[7000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 15001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 35000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 7001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 8000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[8000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[8000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 35001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 90000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 8001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 20000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[20000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[20000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 90001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 170000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 20001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 45000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[45000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[45000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 170001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 300000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 45001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 80000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[80000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[80000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 300001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 550000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 80001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 100000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[100000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.advanced);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[100000]);
        } else if($('.calcEmail').val() >= 550001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 950000 ||
        $('.calcContact').val() >= 100001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 190000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[190000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.advanced);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[190000]);
        } else if($('.calcContact').val() >= 190001 || $('.calcEmail').val() >=  950000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
        }
        
        var totalSendpulse = {
            price: 0,
            name: "",
            subname: "",
            contacs: ""
        };
        totalSendgrid.price = ratesSendgrid[0];
        totalSendgrid.name = ratesSendgrid[1];
        totalSendgrid.subname = ratesSendgrid[2];
        totalSendgrid.contacs = ratesSendgrid[3];
        var totalRates = [totalSendgrid]
        function sortByPrice(arr) {
            arr.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);
        }
        sortByPrice(totalRates);
        if (typeof totalRates[0].price == "undefined" && !totalRates[0].price) {
            $('.priceResult-1').text(totalRates[1].price);
            $('.resilPlan-1').text(totalRates[1].subname);
            $('.contactsCount-1').text(totalRates[1].contacs);
        } else {
            $('.priceResult-1').text(totalRates[0].price);
            $('.resilPlan-1').text(totalRates[0].subname);
            $('.contactsCount-1').text(totalRates[0].contacs);
        }
    }
```

```css
.calcContact {
  width: 100%;
}

.calcEmail {
  width: 100%;
}

.calc__info-item__price {
  width: 100%;
}

.resilPlan-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.contactsCount-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="10000" class="calcContact">
<input type="number" value="10000" class="calcEmail">
<span class="calc__info-item__price">$<span class="priceResult-1">36</span> в мес.</span>
<span class="resilPlan-1">Подписка</span>
<span class="contactsCount-1">9001 - 10000</span>
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`  - ни о чём не говорит ?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, а не просите решение задачи

Comment: Конкретно как сравнить параметры что бы выбирался тот который больше?

Comment: @Евгений Тут действительно надо больше информации. Пример просто не воспроизводится, чтобы увидеть проблему. Но полагаю, что в Вашем случае надо просто разделить выборку. Вот так: `if(($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000) ||
            ($('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Имею ввиду так:
В данном случае у вас будет выполняться условия следующим образом (возьмём первый пример) 
Если выполнять условия таким образом

```
if($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000 ||
            $('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000 {
```

То у Вас получается 4 параметра, которые проверяются одновременно, например `$('.calcContact').val() >= 1` и `$('.calcContact').val() <= 2000` или `$('.calcEmail').val() >= 1` и `$('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000`
То есть по сути - у Вас если выполняется любое из этих условия, то проходит дальше. 
Попробуйте разделить условия так(разделяется скобками):
if(($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000) ||
            ($('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000)) {
Если условие `$('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000` выполнено ИЛИ условие `$('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000` выполнено, то выполняется код.

```js
     var sendgrid = {
        name: "sendgrid",
        2000: 0.00,
        7000: 15.00,
        8000: 25.00,
        20000: 50.00,
        45000: 120.00,
        80000: 200.00,
        100000: 450.00,
        190000: 900.00
    };
    var sendgridContacts = {
        2000: 2000,
        7000: 7000,
        8000: 8000,
        20000: 20000,
        45000: 45000,
        80000: 80000,
        100000: 100000,
        190000: 190000
    };
    var subscribe = {
        sale: "\"Бесплатно\"",
        sub: "Подписка",
        optimal: "\"Оптимальный\"",
        ess: "\"Essentials\"",
        standart: "\"Standard\"",
        prerium: "\"Premium\"",
        basic: "\"Basic\"",
        advanced: "\"Advanced\"",
        enterprise: "\"Enterprise\"",
        ind:  "Индивидуальный"
    };

    var ratesSendgrid = [];

    $('.calcContact, .calcEmail').on('change paste keyup focus', function() {
        if(($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000) ||
            ($('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[2000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.sale);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[2000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 6001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 15000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 2001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 7000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[7000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[7000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 15001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 35000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 7001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 8000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[8000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[8000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 35001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 90000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 8001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 20000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[20000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[20000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 90001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 170000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 20001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 45000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[45000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[45000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 170001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 300000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 45001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 80000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[80000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.basic);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[80000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 300001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 550000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 80001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 100000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[100000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.advanced);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[100000]);
        } else if(($('.calcEmail').val() >= 550001 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 950000) ||
            ($('.calcContact').val() >= 100001 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 190000)) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid[190000]);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgrid.name);
            ratesSendgrid.push(subscribe.advanced);
            ratesSendgrid.push(sendgridContacts[190000]);
        } else if($('.calcContact').val() >= 190001 || $('.calcEmail').val() >=  950000) {
            ratesSendgrid.splice(0, ratesSendgrid.length);
        }

        var totalSendpulse = {
            price: 0,
            name: "",
            subname: "",
            contacs: ""
        };
        totalSendgrid.price = ratesSendgrid[0];
        totalSendgrid.name = ratesSendgrid[1];
        totalSendgrid.subname = ratesSendgrid[2];
        totalSendgrid.contacs = ratesSendgrid[3];
        var totalRates = [totalSendgrid]
        function sortByPrice(arr) {
            arr.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);
        }
        sortByPrice(totalRates);
        if (typeof totalRates[0].price == "undefined" && !totalRates[0].price) {
            $('.priceResult-1').text(totalRates[1].price);
            $('.resilPlan-1').text(totalRates[1].subname);
            $('.contactsCount-1').text(totalRates[1].contacs);
        } else {
            $('.priceResult-1').text(totalRates[0].price);
            $('.resilPlan-1').text(totalRates[0].subname);
            $('.contactsCount-1').text(totalRates[0].contacs);
        }
    })
```

Чтобы сказать точнее, желательно увидеть работающий код.

Comment: он довольно объемный, если подскажите где его можно выложить, могу прямо сейчас, только что попробовал то что вы посоветовали, не помогло, поиск все равно идет основываюсь в первую очередь на параметре количества писем

Comment: @Евгений Если Вам надо и количество первого И количество второго проверять, то вместо или `||` используйте `&&`. Пример: `if(($('.calcContact').val() >= 1 && $('.calcContact').val() <= 2000) &&
            ($('.calcEmail').val() >= 1 && $('.calcEmail').val() <= 6000)) {` Ну и так в каждом условии имеется ввиду. Код Вы можете выложить на `codepen` например.

Comment: [https://codepen.io/johnneon/pen/JjdbKZY?editors=1100] тут полный код, благодарю за советы

Comment: @Евгений Получилось реализовать? Смотрю скобки не прописали, как в примере.

Comment: проставил, результата не дало, на кодпен случайно залил старый вариант, сейчас исправил